# List rows in table with date information

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the beginning of building a simple absence script for teachers to administrate students.

I need to populate the same list of students in 5 tables. One table for each day of the current week (monday to friday).

I have the following code at the moment

***List students SQL query:***

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname, 
 a.student_absence_startdate, a.student_absence_enddate, a.student_absence_type
FROM students s 
LEFT JOIN studentabsence a ON a.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE a.student_absence_startdate 
 IS NULL OR 
  '2012-06-20' 
   BETWEEN 
a.student_absence_startdate AND a.student_absence_enddate
```

This query selects all students and joins another table wich is a linking table that holds the absence information for students.

I the populate the code 5 times like this:

```
<?php
$data = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($list_students)) {
    $data[] = $row;
    }
?>

<table>
  <?php
  foreach($data as $row){
    $class = "";
    if ($row['student_absence_type'] == 2) {$class = " style='background:#f00;'";}
    else if ($row['student_absence_type'] == 3) {$class = " style='background:#8A2BE2;'";}

        echo "<tr><td$class>";
        echo "<a class='ajaxlink' href='#' rel='pages/ajaxAbsence.php?student_id=".$row['student_id']."'>".$row['student_firstname']." ".$row['student_lastname']."</a>";
        echo "</td></tr>\n";
   }
   ?>
</table> <!-- Repeat -->
```

My question is how I should manage the date functions.

As you can see in my SQL query I have hardcoded the dates. I need it to automatically select the date of wich table the students are listed.

for example:

```
table > Monday (2012-07-23)
    the user John Doe has absence information in this span, based on the above query. Let's change the background of <td>
table > Tuesday (2012-07-24)
    the user John Doe has no absence information in this span. Just list him.
etc...
```

I am not expecting you to write my code. I am just curious on how to think. I am fairly new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

The most flagrant error I find in your thoughts is that you don't need those five tables. You'll end up repeating and messing data.

You need different tables, from what I've read.

**Students**

ID, Name, etc..

**Classes**

class_id, name,

**Teachers**

Id_teacher, name, etc

**TeachersInClass** (so you can now which teachers gave a specific class)

id, id_teacher, id_class

Absences

id, id_student, id_class, date

This leaves you a more robust database, and you can play arroud with multiple associations like, which teachers had the most absences in a year... etc etc.

EDIT: Forgot to answer your "real" question.

You can use the PHP [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to manipulate your dates. It's easy to use, and the php.net has a lot of good examples to give you a boost start

Comment: Doing everything five times is really long-winded. Not a real solution, but I also would say that the OP should start with a [normalized ER database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: @feela, Yup, that really sums up basically everything I said.

Comment: I might have been unclear in my OP. The databse is fine. I have the above structure with classes, teachers etc. The linking table is just to keep a record of students who has called in sick. How do you mean I don't need 5 tables? I am talking about HTML tables :)

Comment: OHHH. Your text sequence misleaded me. Nevertheless, I think I answered your question on the bottom lines. If it is a valid DATE field or timestamp, you could use that class and methods...